# gziping strings in a firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

from this blog http://blog.mozilla.org/nfroyd/2012/01/26/compressing-strings-in-js/ it seems like it should be possible, but I'm having trouble implementing (basically as is).

my code is

```
function Accumulator() {
    this.buffer = "";
};

Accumulator.prototype = {
    buffer: null,
    onStartRequest: function(request, context) {},
    onStopRequest: function(request, context, statusCode) {},
    onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count) {
        var stream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIBinaryInputStream);
        stream.setInputStream(inputStream);
        var input = stream.readByteArray(count);
        this.buffer += String.fromCharCode.apply(input);
    }
};

function compress(string) {
    var accumulator = new Accumulator();
    var converter = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/streamconv;1?from=uncompressed&to=gzip"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIStreamConverter);
    // More respecifying input/output types.
    converter.asyncConvertData("uncompressed", "gzip", accumulator, null);
    // Oh, that method doesn't actually convert anything, it just prepares
    // the instance for doing conversion.
    var stream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIStringInputStream);
    stream.data = string;
    converter.onStartRequest(null, null);
    converter.onDataAvailable(null, null, stream, 0, string.length);
    converter.onStopRequest(null, null, 201 /* 417 */);
    return accumulator.buffer;
};
```

but when I use it, I'm getting an error that converter.onRequestStart is not a function.

wondering if I'm doing something obviously wrong?

edit:

1) fixing some obvious mistakes. Ci I didn't catch originally, it's Components.interfaces.

2) original code seemed to have onRequestStart/Stop backwards, they should be onStartRequest/onStopRequest.

with those changes, no longer throws any errors, but also returns an empty string, so nothing seems to be happening. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think I've fixed it (seems to work with my basic tests, including large sites likes espn)

```
function Accumulator() {
    this.buffer = "";
};

Accumulator.prototype = {
    buffer: null,
    onStartRequest: function(request, context) {},
    onStopRequest: function(request, context, statusCode) {},
    onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count) {
        var stream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIBinaryInputStream);
        stream.setInputStream(inputStream);
        var input = stream.readByteArray(count);

        this.buffer += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, input);
    }
};

function compress(string) {
    var accumulator = new Accumulator();
    var converter = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/streamconv;1?from=uncompressed&to=gzip"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIStreamConverter);
    // More respecifying input/output types.
    converter.asyncConvertData("uncompressed", "gzip", accumulator, null);
    // Oh, that method doesn't actually convert anything, it just prepares
    // the instance for doing conversion.
    var stream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIStringInputStream);
    stream.data = string;
    converter.onStartRequest(null, null);
    converter.onDataAvailable(null, null, stream, 0, string.length);
    converter.onStopRequest(null, null, 201 /* 417 */);
    return accumulator.buffer;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, very good solution... can you provide also an equivalent uncompress() function?